# Talking about inanimate objects in plural: they or it

Tags: pronouns

Should I say:

> Wash some apples and put **them** into a vase.

or

> Wash some apples and put **it** into a vase.

Is it correct to use *they* with *inanimate* objects?

Comment: I usually put flowers in a [vase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vase) and apples in a [bowl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowl), but that's just nitpicking.

Answer (score 31):

Yes "they" is correct when referring to inanimate objects. From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/they):

> those ones — used as third person pronoun serving as the plural of he, she, *or it*...

Your second sentence is incorrect because you are referring to multiple apples.

These are both correct.

> Wash *an apple* and put **it** into a vase.
>
> Wash *some apples* and put **them** into a vase.

Answer (score 11):

Unlike the singular "it" which always implies a non-person, the plural pronouns "they", "them", and "those" do not. The plural forms should be used for any plural noun, whether or not it is a person. There aren't actually plural forms of people-specific pronouns.

Therefore, for multiple apple*s*, you put *them* into a container. And for multiple people, you still put *them* into a container.